# Ejabberd Stanza Execution Order (Grouped together)

Tags: xmpp, message, ejabberd, strophe, user-presence

I am trying to find out the execution order of XMPP stanzas, I am using Strophe + Ejabberd and if I send a request like this.

```
<body rid='someRID' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='someSID'>
    <message to='someUser@someDomain' type='chat' xmlns='jabber:client'>
           <body>123</body>
    </message>
    <presence type='unavailable' xmlns='jabber:client' />
</body>
```

Presence stanzas is always executed first and message stanza later. Is there a way to specify order or something like that so that Message stanza is executed first and Presence later.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the server.  [RFC 6120, Section 10.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-10.1) says:

> An XMPP server MUST ensure in-order processing of the stanzas and
> other XML elements it receives over a given input stream from a
> connected client or remote server.